# Read a markdown file in a Symfony project

Tags: file, symfony1, markdown

Is there any recommended way to open a file using Symfony? I'm trying to open a Markdown source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a special *symfony way*.
Just use the normal PHP filesystem functions for that, e.g. [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: Hi!

Before of anything, thanks for the help. I had placed the markdown source file in the following location of the symfony project: doc/markdown/source/ but using the php function file_exists it returns always FALSE. 

The complete path for the file that I desire to open is: /ccam/doc/markdown/source/QuickStart.mdtxt.

Any suggestion for the motive that I can't open the file?

Best regards!

Comment: @Rui Gonçalves: Do you use the relative or the absolute path?

Comment: Hi there!

I was using the absolute path but I now realized that must be used a relative path. Can you tell me why the reason?

Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

The sfMarkdownPlugin README file details the Markdown processing for file contents. In the directions it uses the symfony 'data' directory to store the file, and uses the sfConfig  class to access the file contents.

```
$file = sfConfig::get('sf_data_dir').'/content/about.txt';
if (!is_readable($file))
...
```

You asked for a *symfony* way to read a file, there it is.

See further; http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfMarkdownPlugin/0_1_1?tab=plugin_readme